# Is access to different elements in a C array thread safe?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

Say if I have the following C code:

```c
int my_global_arr[100];
```

or more generally,

```c
some_type *my_global_arr = malloc(some_size * sizeof(some_type);
```

Is it safe to access (both read and write) *different* elements concurrently in multiple threads?
For example, if I have

```c
void *my_thread(void *index){
    int idx = *((int *)(index));
    my_global_arr[idx] = idx;
    return NULL;
}
```

And in `main()`

```c
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
pthread_t thread1, thread2;
pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, my_thread, &a);
pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, my_thread, &b);

pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
```

Will it be guaranteed that the two threads won't interfere with each other?

My experiments:
I tried to run the above "program", expanding to 1000 threads, 100000 times on a x86_64 CPU
with GCC 8.3.0, -std=c99, and it appears that they won't interfere with each other;
however, I don't think such an experiment is good enough to conclude such access is
thread safe on all platform.

**Edit 1**:
This question is about accessing **different** elements in different
threads, not the same element in different threads; that is,
for example, `thread-1` reads/writes to `arr[1]`
while `thread-2` reads/writes to `arr[2]`.

Comment: if you do not modify the same elements as other threads access it is 100% safe

Comment: @P__J__ not convinced that is true on all architectures and all types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can guaranty that at a time, every element accessed only by one thread, it is the thread-safe. Because every element of the array differ from each other(physically) and it means that they are separated sections of memory.

Comment: In the general case, what about types that are smaller than a int, or packed types that are not an exact multiple of an int?  Such types, depending on the system architecture, may need to be accessed by a read/boolean op/write sequence, eg. bytes on a system that only allows 32-bit reads/writes?

Comment: @MartinJames I think in that case that you explain, it is not possible to access by two threads at once.

Comment: Why not?  Thread A reads, modifies a byte in registers by boolean masks etc, is interrupted, thread B reads, modifies an adjacent byte, modifies its byte by masking, writes.  Later, thread A then overwrites the change made by thread B:(

Answer (score 3):

[Edited]

Accessing different elements of an Array in C is perfectly thread safe.

Comment: This answer itself appears to be perfectly correct, but I believe my question is about accessing elements of *different* index, as stated in line 5 in the question.

Comment: Oh. I misread the question then. I will edit my response :)

Comment: I am not covinced that acceses to adjacent bytes of an array, say, is guaranteed safe on architectures that only allow multi-byte accesses, eg 32 bytes at a time, and so require reads, boolean ops and then writes to access types smaller than 32 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing different elements will always be 100% safe.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a good one.  If the basic operations of the cpu work on 32bit pieces of memory, then in thread 1 the cpu would read 32 bits, update the left 16 and then write back 32 bits.  This would overwrite the right 16 which could have been changed by thread 2 between the thread 1 read and write.  However we hope that the author of the original question is not the first person to think of this and in the real world steps are taken by compiler writers to emit the correct code.  Easiest would be to align the array elements on 32 bit boundaries even though the size is 16.